# why does libpostal/pypostal `expand_address` output an array?

Tags: python, geolocation

I'm going through the very excellent [libpostal (pypostal)](https://github.com/openvenues/pypostal) library, which, unfortunately, has no documentation that I can find.

Their example:

```
>>> expand_address('Quatre vingt douze Ave des Champs-Élysées')
[u'92 avenue des champs-elysees', u'92 avenue des champs elysees']
```

outputs an array of 2 identical strings.  What is the utility / purpose of this choice (i.e. how do I use that?)

Thanks

Comment: I found this related issue on github that might clarify some things: https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal/issues/302

Comment: FYI, the strings aren't identical, the first has a dash, and the second doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It does the same for both expanding the address and parsing the address into city,state,zip etc.

The first element is always the most probabilistic correct answer which you can use.

Comment: basically, it expands the ST to the street and other short words in the address expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it should be made very clear  `expand_address()` was not intended to be particularly smart about addresses. The goal and purpose of it is to make indexable/searchable addresses.<sup>[1](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal#:%7E:text=The%20expand_address%20API%20converts%20messy,hashing%2C%20etc.)</sup> It "standardizes" them using simpler algorithms that don't utilize NLP.<sup>[2](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal/issues/302#issuecomment-358268077:%7E:text=expand_address%20does%20not%20use,intended%20functionality.)</sup> Exactly why, I'm not sure. There are probably performance considerations.

Sadly, as you've stated, documentation is sparse. I'm currently experimenting w/version `v1.1-alpha` but my sources may have been related to older versions, so mileage may vary.

---

The other answers here are wrong or uneducated at best.

One by one, I'll addresses the inaccuracies found in answers here.

> It does the same for both expanding the address and parsing the address into city,state,zip etc.

I don't understand what "same" is here, but `parse_address()` returns a list of tuples representing a *single* address in its constituent parts. `expand_address()` returns a list of strings containing full addresses. I guess returning a list means they're the "same", lol.

> The first element [returned from expand_address()] is always the most probabilistic correct answer which you can use.

Not even remotely true. Results are not ranked or ordered in any way.<sup>[3](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal/issues/302#issuecomment-358268077:%7E:text=the%20results%20are%20unordered)</sup>

From what I've gleaned, one of its primary normalization mechanisms is language detection. The language probability is *scored* and I have to assume there's some threshold for results for which languages are included, but they are not *ordered*. Score isn't included for the results either. Interesting note, if this description of `expand_address()` falls into your use case, it can be improved by passing it a language.<sup>[4](https://github.com/openvenues/pypostal/blob/master/postal/expand.py#L9:%7E:text=expand_address,languages,-%3DNone%2C%20**)</sup> Languages and regions aren't 1:1, but that's what we're given, and it may be helpful.

An example is '4123 Griffin Ave Los Angeles CA' which contains Spanish words obviously, so the language recognition registers some relatively high score for Spanish for this address. For Americans it's probably obvious that CA is a state abbreviation, but in Spanish the word for 'street' is 'calle', so it must consider that as a possibility as well. We could pass `language=['en']` to `expand_address()` which would rule out street suffixes like 'calle' for the string 'CA'. Again, using language is not 1:1 with region, so this may not always work as desired.

> basically, it expands the ST to the street and other short words in the address expansion.

Sort of. In the general sense, that's what "expansion" is intended to mean in this context. It often does do its expansion like this, but it can also return things that look like abbreviations, eg. `ca` which could be `california` or `canada` but may not be either. Expansion depends on the `address_components` settings which determine which parts are expanded or not. For example, by excluding ADDRESS_STREET from expansion will not convert `st` to `street`. There are defaults that affect what's expanded.<sup>[5](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal/issues/7#:%7E:text=if%20you%20set%20.address_options,different%20output)</sup>

---

The summary here is that `expand_address()` is for generating various standardized or normalized addresses in a format that's more machine readable, in a sense.

Converting human entered addresses to this normalized format means it's possible to do things like finding a business at a specific address in a database in a quick, consistent, reliable way.

It does not take location into account.

---

To be honest though, I'm struggling to imagine a good use for it.

It feels like `parse_address()` does the first half of what I need, then `expand_address()` could do the second half, but since it's not working with something structured like the results from `parse_address()` and it doesn't take location into account like `parse_address()` does, it can't generate something consistent. I still find myself needing to use something like [Google Address Validation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/overview) to get back something "normalized".

Comment: Thank you for sharing your research. The disconnect between parsing and expanding is something also seen in the use of the Python usaddress module. In that scenario, since we can get the street type suffix, we can target that field directly for expansion. Maybe the same process can be done with libpostal as shown here? https://gist.github.com/Insighttful/67454d5156dd3cb1c3e3cdff8ab95cbb

Comment: The initial issues I've found with libpostal's `expand_address` are two-fold: first the issue this question references: 1. If you want to have an idempotent process to always expand addresses in the same manner, determining which choice from the response array is a problem that needs a custom solution. 2. Even in common scenarios, libpostal's expansion choices can be technically correct, but practically wrong. Take for instance: `123 Test Dr, Testville, TX 1234`, multiple array results will contain 'doctor' instead of 'drive'. `123 test doctor testville tx 1234`.

Comment: Yeah, that's another use case where these concepts don't translate well into practice. As you mention, determining which choice to use requires an additional step to solve the problem. Again, "testing" each possibility with Google Address Validation or similar is probably going to be the simplest and most reliable way. It still may be redundant though, making libpostal unnecessary even. GPT might be another option here; it will be good at the "drive" vs "doctor" issue for sure. Prompt: "Which of these strings is most likely to be a valid street address? 1...doctor... 2...drive..." Answer: "2".

Comment: Because I have a high volume of addresses, it would be cost prohibitive to use an API to standardize them. I ended up writing a custom implementation that leverages datamade's US Address https://usaddress.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#details. It uses US Address to parse the address elements and a local lookup on US Post Office's address standards to uniformly contract or expand the address elements as needed. https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm